# OBIEE Logical Expression - Sum by attribute

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, obiee

I am trying create a calculated column in the logical table source expression builder.

In my case, an order is made up of line items, and each line has a quantity.

I want to add a new attribute based on the total quantity of all line items on the order.

What I want to do is something like:

```
SUM(quantity) BY ORDER_ID
```

But that syntax doesn't work.

Here is what I have:

```
CASE WHEN SUM("FINQ".""."XXDW"."xxdw_f_orders_items"."quantity") >= 100 THEN '>=100' ELSE '<100' END
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a SUM. As I said on the forums you must create a physical expression so that the calculation is executed pre-aggregation. Ergo no SUM needed as the logic will be executed row-by-row. You don't want to know the size of a bundle of orders but of each order.

If you're doing this against SampleApp Lite it's simply a new logical column in D3 Orders (Fact Attributes) with the following physical expression

```
"CASE WHEN "F10 Revenue Facts (Order grain)"."Revenue" >= 100 then '>=100' else '<100' end
```

Done.

Edit: Please do close your forum threads. Other users would like to benefit as well.

Comment: I believe I do need a sum because each order is made up of multiple items (rows). If I use your logic it will perform the grouping at the item level. I want the grouping to be determined at the order level, which can be comprised of many rows.

Comment: In other words the order and order items table have been denormalized into a single table. I need the quantity summed by the order number, not at the row level of order-items

Comment: Ok if you need to roll up children then what you "bin" is basically a level-based measure. Interesting that you dont have a physical header representing the total. But as long as all items use linear aggregation that's fine. Header-applied discounts etc will not be possible though.